# Opimal Magento server setup?

Tags: magento2, server, optimization

With Magento 2 being around for a bit now, some of you probably have experience with the optimal setup already.

What would be the best server configuration for an optimised Magento store? Backend cache, sessions, PHP/Opcode caching - any combination of Redis, Varnish, Memcache, APC, or something that I'm not aware of. I will be experimenting with setups and would like to know what is working best for you guys and if something has changed with Magento 2.

Comment: It's no different to M1 from a hosting perspective, the same platforms used for M1 are the same you would use for M2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about production.

- You should always enable the PHP Opcode cache
- Session caching using [memcache](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/memcache/memcache.html) (if you use PHP 7, you must use memcache*d* with a *d*)
- Page caching using [Varnish](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html) or [Redis](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html)

We *don't* recommend using file system page caching in production because performance is poor.

Comment: Thanks, however this is more of general advise and takes 30 minutes to set up. I'm rather looking for the absolutely optimal setup, no matter how much tweaking it would need.

Comment: Varnish and Redis are completely different tools, you can't use them interchangeably (ie. Varnish or Redis), because they have nothing in common. You use Varnish as a frontend cache and Redis as a backend cache store.